# Laravel 5.5 get where two column egal

Tags: laravel-5

i have a table name `Services`

`id | name | limit_patient`

`1 | ORL | 10`

`2 | pediatre | 15`

how to create a function where if name equal limit_patient do this else check ID 2

Comment: `if name equal limit_patient` what does it mean?

Comment: Yes of course right

Comment: Still not clear can give example of your query/question?